# Google Cloud App Engine stopped connecting to Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-sql

I've got a J2EE web application deployed to Google Cloud App Engine, which connects to a MySQL DB on Cloud SQL. All of a sudden it's stopped working. The GCP URL works fine and points to the correct web UI. I've re-tested the DB connection string on Google App Engine local host server, and it works absolutely fine. Public IP is enabled on Cloud SQL and my home network IP address is authorised. But clearly the cloud app engine code isn't talking to the Cloud SQL db.

Happy to share relevant code, but not sure what code would be helpful to share, as the app engine cloud URL is working, and the DB connection string is testing fine on localhost.

Does anyone have any trouble shooting tips on how I might get to the bottom of it? Has anything changed recently with GAE/Cloud SQL?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you check your App Engine logs and see if there are any errors? If so, please update your post. Also, are you connecting via TCP or Unix socket? Let me know if this helps https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#java

Comment: can you share how are you connect your GAE to Cloud SQL?